# Best way to fire events when single elements in the document becomes ready

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, dom, promise

I'm developing a web application that because of performance concerns is heavily reliant on Ajax functionality.  I'm attempting to make parts of each page available while longer running modules load.

The issue is that I want to kick off the Ajax requests as soon as possible (in the head of the document).  This part works fine; the issue is on rare occasion, the Ajax call will come back before the area that I want to load the Ajax data into is present on the page.  This causes the data to not be loaded.

To get around the issue I started using script tags below each of my containers that resolve a JQuery promise to let the code know that the area is available.

EDIT: I want to load the data into the area **as soon as it becomes available (before full document load)**.

The current pseudo code looks like this:

```
<head>
    <script> 
        var areaAvailablePromise = new $.Deferred();
        $.when(areaAvailablePromise, myAjaxFunction()).then(function(){
            // load data into the element.
        });
    </script>
</head>

<!-- much later in the document -->

<div class="divIWantToLoadAjaxContentInto"></div>
<script>
    areaAvailablePromise.resolve();
</script>
```

My question is: is there ANY better way to handle this situation?  Every one knows that inline scripts are blocking and are bad for performance.  Also, I feel that this is going to lead to cluttered code with micro-script tags all over the place.

Comment: what about window.onload

Comment: I would like to load the Ajax data into the element as soon as it becomes available (before the entire document is ready.)

Comment: if you don't rely on other Elements after the specified one you want to make Ajax call for it so your way is the best

Comment: Put your code right before closing the `body` tag, this way the browser will render all the html and then execute the scripts. Also you can refer to js files asycronously if the don't need to interact each others to eventually prevent the blocking of scripts...

Comment: It sounds like the way I'm doing it is the only way to achieve the very specific timing that I want.

Answer (score 0):

Put your (whole) `<script>` tag just after the element.

HTML is parsed from top to bottom, so the element will be loaded already.

Answer (score 0):

No. There really is no better way to my knowledge.

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
    <head>
        <script src="jquery.min.js"></script>
        <script src="q.min.js"></script>
        <script>
            var elD = Q.defer();
            var dataP = Q($.ajax(…));
            Q.spread([elD.promise, dataP], function (el, data) {
                …
            }).done();
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        …
        <div id="foo"></div>
        <script>elD.resolve($("#foo"));</script>
        …
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use:

> $(document).ready(   handler )

(recommended)and also has contracted form:

> $(handler)

exemple:

```
$(function(){ 
  alert("OK"); 
})
```

read more: http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: duplicate of @Satpal's answer.